# "You need 220 M on disc /boot" What I have to do?

Tags: updates

I'm new on elementary OS and Linux. 
I've to update the software (using the software update application) but when I click "update now" I've got a message that says: clean the trash and use "sudo apt-get clean". 
I did it but it doesn't work anyway.

Can someone help me? What I have to do?
(sorry for the bad english)

edit (1): running df -h I have:

```
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
udev            3,4G  4,0K    3,4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           691M  1,7M    690M   1% /run
/dev/dm-1       910G  122G    742G  15% /
none            4,0K     0    4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M  4,0K    5,0M   1% /run/lock
none            3,4G  156K    3,4G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K    100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2       237M  160M     65M  72% /boot
/dev/sda1       511M  3,4M    508M   1% /boot/efi
```

edit (2): using Gparted I have this.
[image]

and I can't resize the partition

Comment: When you run `df -h`, how much space is available on your hard drives? (You can paste the result into your question, if it would help.)

Comment: @Wolf I edited my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/boot` partition will be locked in `gparted` while your operating system is running (as the partition is mounted and in use). Instead, boot into [a "live CD" (or drive)](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) to modify the partition while the operating system is not in use.

You'll want at least twice as much space in your boot partition (~500 MB), and you could probably size down that EFI partition (Ubuntu [recommends](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) 100-250 MB instead of your 512 MB). And this should go without saying, but **remember to backup** any important data before proceeding in case you mess up your drive.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated enough space for your `boot` partition (where the kernel goes).

Boot into a live session with the elementary installer, and then follow [this tutorial](https://partedmagic.com/using-gparted/) to shrink your `root` partition to free up some room, and then resize the `boot` partition so it is around 500MB.

Comment: thanks! When I installed the OS I haven't touched the default settings, I hope it will work!

Comment: Gparted doesn't work. I installed it using the terminal and I can see the partitions of my disk. But when I select the /boot I can't use "resize" because it's disabled!

Comment: Ah, this will be because it is currently mounted. If you still have the USB flash drive with the elementary installer then I believe that has GParted installed. Boot from that and try again.